error get data to one data using vue router and laravel
I learning Vue in use Vue router, make crud SPA application
component to show all data:
<template>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">title</th>
                <th scope="col">description</th>
                <th scope="col">author</th>
                <th scope="col">edit</th>
                <th scope="col">delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="post in posts">
                <td>
                    <router-link v-if="post && post.id" :to="{ name: 'post.show', params: { id: post.id }}">
                        {{post.title}}
                    </router-link>
                </td>
                <td>{{post.description}}</td>
                <td>{{post.author}}</td>
                <td>
                    <router-link class="btn btn-primary" v-if="post && post.id" :to="{ name: 'post.edit', params: { id: post.id }}">Edit</router-link>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" @click.prevent="deletePost(post.id)" href="#">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

my vue router link
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/post",
        name: "post.index",
        component: () => import('./components/post/Index.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: "/post/:id/edit",
        name: "post.edit",
        component: () => import('./components/post/Edit.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: "/post/:id",
        name: "post.show",
        component: () => import('./components/post/Show.vue'),
    },
];`


method to get data about one data:

`        getPost() {
            axios.get(`/api/post/${this.$route.params.id}`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.post = response.data.data
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error.message)
                })
        },

to show data I use {{this.post.description}} and in data() { return { post:null }}
if I try to get data about one data, get error "Error: Missing required param "id"", however
<router-link v-if="post && post.id" :to="{ name: 'post.show', params: { id: post.id}}">                      {{post.title}}</router-link>
I send data about id
I try to get data about one data

solve this problem, I use resource  send to frontend data from backend, and in conntroller use this url, return ['id' => $id, 'data' =>$data] and work

Please post an answer with your solution.

solve this problem, I use resource send to frontend data from backend, and in conntroller use this url, return ['id' => $id, 'data' => $data] and work, when 'id' get in request

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
